# What is an efficient method of collision detection for handling lots of objects?

Tags: collision-detection, box2d, physics

In my game, I have plenty of objects that can collide. Literally, most of them can collide with each other. The problem I'm facing is that I can't come up with some good collision detection. How can I resolve collisions for lots of objects in such way that I don't end up with class that has more than 1000 lines of code with enormous conditional constructs like this?

```
    if (firstBodyUserData == "rocket"
            && secondBodyUserData == "car_body") {
        resolveRocketAndCarBodyCollision(firstBody, secondBody, contactData);
    } else if (firstBodyUserData == "rocket"
            && secondBodyUserData == "gas_tank")
        resolveRocketAndGasTankCollision(firstBody, secondBody, contactData);
    //...many more dumb lines of code for every particular object in my game
```

And don't forget about all these "resolving methods" after if statements.

To make question more specific, I use Box2D  with its ContactListener and Artemis-odb entity-component-system framework so I don't really have classes for my entities and that kind of exacerbates the problem but main question is in resolving bunch of different types of collisions.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is register collision callbacks for each kind of body.

```
// You have a map from bodies to functions of bodies.
Map<BodyData, Function<BodyData> > collisionCallbacks;
// Invoke the function associated with that kind of body.
collisionCallbacks[firstBodyUserData].Invoke(secondBodyUserData);

// An example collision function
void resolveRocketCollision(BodyData data)
{
     // This is also really horrible. You don't want to be checking conditions 
     // like this. Instead, you will want to indirect this one step further to
     // the *type* of the object, using virtual function calls.
     if(data == "car_body") ...
     else if(data == "gas_tank") ...

     // That is, it should look like this:
     if (data.HasProperty(Health))
          ...
     if (data.HasProperty(Explodes))
          ..
     ...
}

// Registering the function
collisionCallbacks["rocket"] = resolveRocketCollision;
```

### Avoiding function pointers

In Java, you don't have function pointers, so it might be better to have an interface with a "resolvecollision" method like this:

```
public interface CollisionResolver
{
    void Resolve(BodyData bodyData, CollisionData collision);
}
```

Then your map would be something like this:

```
Map<BodyData, CollisionResolver> collisionCallbacks;
```

And you invoke it like this:

```
collisionCallbacks[firstBodyUserData].Resolve(secondBodyData, collisionData);
```

### Avoiding a big static map

Obviously it's bad practice to carry around a big map of collision callbacks. You will have to use (drum roll) *object oriented programming*. Instead of storing strings as your user data, store the objects themselves. Then your function just becomes:

```
void ResolveCollision(BodyData body1, BodyData body2, CollisionData collisionData)
{
    body1.Resolve(body2, collisionData);
}
```

And, each of your bodies implements the `CollisionResolver` interface. For example, if you want a rocket to explode anything that has "health" you do this:

```
class Rocket implements CollisionResolver
{
   public void Resolve(BodyData otherBody, CollisionData collisionData)
   {
       if (otherBody.HasProperty(Health))
       {
           ExplodeRocket();
           otherBody.Die();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can this be achieved in not functional language, for example in Java?

Comment: Yes, using Java [lambdas or anonymous internal classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734052/simulate-function-pointer). You can also just implement a function in your user data class that gets called directly.

Comment: So i have collisonCallbacks for half of my collidable objects? And how do i initialize these maps?

Comment: Yes, you have collision callbacks for every *type* of object that needs different behavior when colliding. If you're clever you can get this down to just 2 or 3 types. You register a callback whenever the object gets created. It'd be helpful to know *why* you need a big map of different collision resolutions. Usually you just attach a "sensor" object to your entity, then check collisions on that sensor for relevant types of objects.

Comment: I added more code to make this more clear.

Comment: Now it doesn't fit entity-component system design at all;)

Comment: Uh, yeah it does. Replace `class Rocket` with `class Exploder` or whatever component type you're using.